# How to output the function into a File

Tags: php, function, return, fopen

I have this function:

```
function permGen($a,$b,$c,$d,$e,$f,$g) {
    foreach ($a as $key1 => $value1){
        foreach($b as $key2 => $value2){
            foreach($c as $key3 => $value3) {
            print trim($d[rand(0,count($d)-1)]).trim($value1).trim($e[rand(0,count($e)-1)]).trim($value2).trim($f[rand(0,count($f)-1)]).trim($value3).$g;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

THIS IS the output that I need and it works perfectly when I'm printing on screen.

Assuming, I define all arguments without any problems. Now here is the problem, when I put permGen($arguments....); it works. But when I try and write this in a file by file handling like this,

```
$handle = fopen('new.txt', 'w+');
fwrite($handle, permGen($arguments...));
```

It doesnt seem to work. It creates a file but with nothing in it. I tried **replacing** print with return. Then it just gave 1 loop in new.txt and nothing else.Nothing seems to work as per what I want to get as my output.

Thanks

Comment: Use `file_put_contents()` , for example. Don't forget `FILE_APPEND` flag

Comment: Yeah, use `file_put_contents()`. Later, to retrieve the data you stored, you can use `file_get_content()`.

For more info, refer to :
http://php.net/file_put_contents   | 
http://www.php.net/file_get_contents

Comment: file_put_contents() doesnt work. I tried: file_put_contents('new.txt',normGen($arguments...)); Doesnt work

Comment: `Print` outputs content to the browser. Therefor your function returns nothing and thats why there is nothing in your file. Use the aproach of chanchal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function permGen($handle, $a,$b,$c,$d,$e,$f,$g) {
    foreach ($a as $key1 => $value1){
        foreach($b as $key2 => $value2){
            foreach($c as $key3 => $value3) {
                fwrite(
                    $handle, 
                    trim($d[rand(0,count($d)-1)]).trim($value1).trim($e[rand(0,count($e)-1)]).trim($value2).trim($f[rand(0,count($f)-1)]).trim($value3).$g;
                );
            }
        }
    }
}

// To write to a file
$handle = fopen('new.txt', 'w+');
permGen($handle, $other, $arguments, ...);
fclose($handle);

// To write to normal output (browser, whatever)
$handle = fopen('php://output', 'w');
permGen($handle, $other, $arguments, ...);
fclose($handle);
```

**EDIT**

If you don't want to modify your function in any way, then you can use output buffering to capture the printed output:

```
ob_start();
permGen($arguments...);
$output = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

file_put_contents(
    'new.txt',
    $output,
    FILE_APPEND
);
```

Comment: Hello sir,

I do not want to tamper with my function. That is, I dont want to create the file simulaneously.. I want to put the contents of my output. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
function permGen($a,$b,$c,$d,$e,$f,$g) {
    $output = '';
    foreach ($a as $key1 => $value1){
        foreach($b as $key2 => $value2){
            foreach($c as $key3 => $value3) {
                $output .= trim($d[rand(0,count($d)-1)]).trim($value1).trim($e[rand(0,count($e)-1)]).trim($value2).trim($f[rand(0,count($f)-1)]).trim($value3).$g;
            }
        }
    }

    return $output;
}
```

Comment: Hello, This isnt working. You cannot define an undefined $output like that

Comment: Where you see undefined $output?

Comment: I checked too.It just outputs the function.It doesnt write the function in the file.

Comment: Can you paste your file content here?